# Changing database from localhost to outside host

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have my site up and running, and I need to change now database to outside host I just purchased, but it keeps showing error...

I use CakePHP, I configure database.php file
Funny part is that layout works, it shows as it's new database selected, but view inside isn't working, it keeps telling me that there is no that file found...

I don't know what is relation between database.php and files, but it simply won't work...

If I'm move to new database host, what should I change beside database.php?

Is CakePHP caching data somewhere or something that I should change/delete/update?
Or is there another file that should be changed?

Please help!
I need this, users are on site and keeps seeing errors!

Comment: make the problem simplier. from the machine with the code try from the commandline a connection to the remote mysql server.  Confirm you can run normal mysql commands. This will help you figure out if its mysql or Cake that is the issue.

Comment: Can you post the specific error being thrown? You should not have to change anything except the values in `app/config/database.php`.

Comment: It gets connected to mysql for sure, there is small chat at bottom on every page, and it's working, but other pages wont... like CakePHP can't find them... If something is wrong inside database.php will that lead to page not found error or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities: If you moved from a windows test server to a Linux production server, you could have case differences in your names.

Another thought is that you did not actually upload all the code files to the server.

Comment: There were few tables missing that CakePHP required, and that was the error... It was just showing page not found because it's a error... Thank you all! ;)